# webpack: bundle is now INVALID. webpack: bundle is now VALID

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have just started working on React.js recently. I am following some tutorials and testing some examples from it. But, as I reached an example of props, it doesn't run. I can't understand the problem. Following is the output on my CMD:

```
    webpack: bundle is now INVALID.
    Hash: b3302b07f8d42d8d5049
    Version: webpack 1.13.1
    Time: 297ms
    chunk    {0} index.js (main) 906 kB
    [76] ./main.js 582 bytes {0} [built]
    + 247 hidden modules
    webpack: bundle is now VALID.
```

Here is Props.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <h1>{this.props.headerProp}</h1>
            <h2>{this.props.contentProp}</h2>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

App.defaultProps = {
   headerProp: "Header from props...",
   contentProp: contentProp = "Content from props..."
}

export default App;
```

And here is main.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './Props.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));

export default App;
```

Comment: This looks like output from a hot-reload.  Try just running the `webpack` command in the same directory as your `webpack.conf.js` file.  You should see correct error output.

Comment: The 'INVALID' part is a red herring. It just means that webpack is about to do an update. This `contentProp: contentProp = "Content from props..."` does not look right. Try `contentProp: "Content from props..."`

Comment: I ran 'webpack' command but it doesn't show any error output. @DavinTryon

Comment: @DavidGilbertson It worked. Thank you!